# Erro ao exportar Excel utilizando Maatwebsite / Laravel-Excel

Tags: laravel, microsoft-excel, exportação

A exportação para excel funciona bem até uns 10000 registros mas acima disso ele me retorna o erro: 
"127.0.0.1 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"
Alguém já teve esse problema?

```
public function getUsersRegion($region){
        $region = is_array($region) ? $region : array($region);
        $users = DB::table("users")
                    ->join("regions", "users.region", "=", "regions.id")
                    ->select("users.id" , "users.avatar", "users.first_name", "users.last_name", "users.email", "regions.name", "users.ref_code", "users.banned")
                    ->whereIn("users.region", $region)
                    ->orderBy("users.id", "desc")                   
                    ->get();
            return $users;
    }

    public function export($region, $format) {
        $retorno = $this->getUsersRegion($region);
        Excel::create('Painel Gerenciador de Conteudo', function($excel) use ($retorno, $format){
            $excel->sheet('Painel Gerenciador de Conteudo', function($sheet) use ($retorno, $format){
                $sheet->loadView('exports.export')->with('retorno',$retorno)->with('format',$format);
            });
        })->export($format);
    }
```

Comment: Já tive problemas com ela, e no meu caso, ela chorava com bem menos registros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Costuma ocorrer muito um erro 500 seguido de uma página em branco. Infelizmente, essa biblioteca de geração de excel do Laravel não consegue se comportar muito bem quando a quantidade de dados geradas é muito grande.

Eu sugeriria a você usar algumas funções que reduzem o tamanho da carga de registros que é feito na memória, como por exemplo o método `chunk`.

Vou mostrar uma implementação que fiz, você pode adaptar à sua necessidade:

```
    $query = Usuario::where('status', '=', 1);

    return Excel::create("relatorio-usuarios-ativos", function ($excel) use($query) {

        $excel->setTitle('Usuários')->sheet('usuarios', function ($sheet) use($query) {

            $sheet->appendRow([
                'ID', 
                'NOME',
                'IDADE',
            ]);

            // Os dados são carregados de 50 em 50, para não sobrecarregar a memória
            $query->chunk(50, function ($usuarios) use ($sheet) {

                foreach ($usuarios as $usuario) {

                    $sheet->appendRow([
                       $usuario->id,
                       $usuario->nome,
                       $usuario->idade,
                    ]);                        
                }
            });

            $sheet->row(1, function ($row) {
                $row->setFontColor('#ffffff')->setBackground('#00458B');
            });
        });

    })->download('xlsx');
```

Veja acima que eu evitei usar `loadView`, porque além da memória já usada na consulta e na geração do `Excel`, você estaria forçando o seu servidor a fazer o parser também dessa view para montar o Excel.

Se de tudo acima não resolver o problema, aconselho usar `CSV`, que é nativo do PHP e a geração é bem mais rápida, comportando um volume maior de dados, com baixo custo de memória.

Comment: Deu certo com a sua solução.